# How to merge remote github repos to local correctly

Tags: git, github, repository

I am currently working in two locations and am encountering problems in terms of keeping my local repos on both machines current.  Once I have committed and pushed changes to github on one machine, if I then try to pull the repo to the other local machine I inevitably get errors.  I am sure I am doing something wrong, what is the correct procedure for achieving a seamless workflow between the two local machines in relation to my remote repos.  This is in relation to both the master and branches I am working on.  Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to elaborate on "errors".

Comment: showing your git commands may help

Comment: Sorry I wasn't specific I was sure it was a very basic question.  The errors that cropped up were various ones but it was clear that I was doing something procedurally wrong due to a lack of experience.  Thank you though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During development you usually want to rebase your local changes onto the remote HEAD.

Assuming you have no uncommitted changes locally, simply use `git pull --rebase`.
If you do have uncommitted changes, either commit them or `git stash` them, then rebase and then unstash them using `git stash pop`.